# Wireshark Time-Sequence-Graph (Stevens)

Tags: tcp, wireshark

I need help explain this graph http://www.picamatic.com/view/9018094_Untitled/

I need to find out the TCP’s slowstart phase begins and ends, and where congestion avoidance takes over.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat tough to see since there are no grid lines, but we can estimate. Slow start is characterized by exponential growth, so it appears that on the 6th burst, the packets being sent between 1.0 and 1.1 seconds, that the exponential growth of packets being sent out has stopped and instead turned linear indicating it has entered congestion avoidance.